# Create aggregation function to report most popular in Google DataTable

Tags: google-visualization

I have a Google DataTable which looks like this:

    `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'City');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Model');

    data.addColumn('number', 'Sold');
    data.addRows([
    ["Melbourne","Ford",10],
    ["Perth","Ford",2],
    ["Melbourne","Ford",7],
    ["Melbourne","Holden",25],
    ["Perth","Holden",25],
    ["Melbourne","Holden",12],
    ["Melbourne","Ford",11]
    ]);`

What I would like to do is group by City and report the Model with the highest cumulative Sold value for that City.

The result returned would be :

`City         Model
Melbourne    Holden
Perth        Ford`

From my reading of the Google Visualisation API it is possible to write a custom aggregation function but that is beyond my limited experience.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This would require a double grouping: the first time to get total sold per model per city, and the second time to get the most popular model.

```
var g1 = google.visualization.data.group(data, [0, 1], [{
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Total Sold',
    column: 2,
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
}]);
// create a view to merge columns 1 and 2 together for the grouping below
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(g1);
view.setColumns([0, {
    type: 'string',
    label: 'Model QTy Sold',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        var o = {model: dt.getValue(row, 1), sold: dt.getValue(row, 2)};
        return JSON.stringify(o);
    }
}]);
var g2 = google.visualization.data.group(data, [0], [{
    type: 'string'
    label: 'Most Popular'
    aggregation: function (values) {
        var max = null, ret = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < values; i++) {
            var o = JSON.parse(values[i]);
            if (max == null || o.sold > max) {
                max = o.sold;
                ret = o.model;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}]);
```

`g2` should contain model with highest sales grouped by city.  If there is a tie between two models, this will return the first model in the `values` array (likely `values` will be ordered by model name, but this is not guaranteed).

Answer (score 0):

The edits I made to asgallant's second grouping were:

```
var g2 = google.visualization.data.group(view, [0], [{
type: 'string',
label: 'Most Popular',
column: 1,
aggregation: function (values) {
    var max = null, ret = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var o = JSON.parse(values[i]);
        if (max == null || o.sold > max) {
            max = o.sold;
            ret = o.model;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

}]);